# Deducting time in excel

Tags: excel, vba, date, datetime, time

I have two text boxes using excel vba.  I have some code where I deduct or add time hh:mm:ss from hh:mm:ss.

Adding seems to be fine.
If I add 00:00:15 to 12:00:00 it comes out as 12:00:15 correctly.

If I deduct 00:00:15 from 12:00:00 it comes out as a decimal. I have been using:

`timevalue(textbox1) + timevalue(textbox2)` (This seems to work)

`timevalue(textbox1) - timevalue(textbox2)` (This doesn’t work)

Also is there a way of combining date and time in a similar way. I.e I want to deduct 1 day and 00:00:15 from the day and time..? Rather than separating out date and time boxes..?
Any ideas please?

Comment: Why do you even use `TimeValue()`? You can just add and subtract the values without using that function.

Comment: Try `CDate(TimeValue(textbox1) - TimeValue(textbox2))`

Comment: The decimal you're getting is _0.499826389_.  If you consider hours as a fraction of a 1 day - 0.25 would be 6am, 0.5 would be midday, 0.75 would be 6pm.  `0.49` comes just before midday - 15 minutes to be exact.

Comment: Thanks Darren - that’s works a treat!